# App restricted by facebook

Tags: facebook, restriction

My application has been restricted by facebook :
"The app can no longer upload or tag photos"

This app upload otomaticaly picture when an AUTHENTICATE user want it!
So there is no reason to block it as we have the total agreement of the user.

Is there any way to unlock this situation as this is a profetional app and we are loosing money

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the permissions your app is requesting are still good ?

Comment: i got this on my action:
A moratorium has been placed on this action type.
Due to the breaking change that was announced in October, your action type has been restricted and is no longer available to your users. We encourage you to submit a new action type that helps people share meaningful stories with friends on Facebook.

Comment: May it be related to this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/) ? Especially the following : **Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API
We have found that posting content via API (stream.publish) on a friend's wall lead to a high incidence of user dissatisfaction (hiding content, blocking the app). After the migration period, posting content to friends' timelines via stream.publish will no longer be allowed. Please use the Feed Dialog for posting.**

Comment: Ok but how do i unlock the app for now?

Comment: P.S.: we never post on friends'wall... so simple Publishing should be enough !